# Output numbers in table. Python

Tags: python-3.x

Output digits to staircase table. Python
Hi everyone!

I'm start learning python (Nested Loops)

I'm write the following code:

```
for i in range(9, 2, -1):
    x = 2
    for j in range(i):
        print(x, end=' ')
        x = x+1
    print()
```

It's output is:

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

2 3 4 5 6 7 8

2 3 4 5 6 7

2 3 4 5 6

2 3 4 5

2 3 4

2 3

But I need this output:

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

4 5 6 7 8 9 10

5 6 7 8 9 10

....

9 10

What I should change in my code to receive correct output? Please advice

Comment: `for j in range(i)` Look at the documentation or a tutorial to see what `range(i)` does. How to make `range` start at a given number is covered in any basic article on the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range (2,10):
    for j in range (i,11):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

produces this output:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 6 7 8 9 10
6 7 8 9 10
7 8 9 10
8 9 10
9 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You could also do away with the inner loop and multiple `print` calls and use `print(*range(i, 11), sep=" ")` as the entire body of the outer loop.